# Fade in/out different text in hero unit using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "Hero" unit, which has the code as follows:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dapibus Euismod Mollis</h1>
        <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more »</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is have four or five different `<h1>`'s and `<p>`'s and then have each one fade through to the next one after five seconds, looping back to the begining at the end. What I have tried so far is having something like:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dapibus Euismod Mollis</h1>
        <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more »</a></p>
        <h1>Dapibus Euismod Mollis</h1>
        <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more »</a></p>
        <h1>Dapibus Euismod Mollis</h1>
        <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more »</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then hiding and showing the content, but that is a really ugly solution that doesn't really work. Can anyone suggest anything else?

Comment: You want to fadeIn each element one after the other?

Comment: Not exactly. A similar example is the area at the top of the homepage at http://www.mediafire.com/ where it fades between title/content every few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this jquery plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ it is very easy to use. You just need to place you `h1` and `p` inside a `div` which will make it a `slide` and place them inside `<div class="slideshow">` parent div. Call it as follows

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
   fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6243/)

**UPDATE**

You can also use `pause: 1` if you want to make the slide pause if you mouse over the slide

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
       fx: 'fade',
       pause: 1
});
```

[FIDDLE WITH PAUSE](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6244/)

Answer (score 1):

I would make a recursive function whcih fades one in, the out. It then calls itself using the next selector to grab the next element as it parameter, when when .next() returns null, picks the first element again. You will want to put some kind of base case for when you want it to stop of course. So:

```
function cycle(elem) {
    if(!baseCase){
        elem.fadeIn(400).delay(4000).fadeOut(400)
        if(elem.next()){
            cycle(elem.next());
        }else{
            cycle(first elem);
        }
    }
}
```

jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pKkX/
I had to make a few changes, such as waiting for the fadeOut to end before recursing. The !false is a placeholder for your base case, so in your version it would be `!someBoolean` where someBoolean is true when you want it to stop looping.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't really understand what you mean. Could you make a jsFiddle example for it?

Comment: @BenedictLewis There you go